# Jmeter : can i need 100 users for check dashboard after login

Tags: authentication, session, jmeter, load, performance-testing

can i need to create 100 different user in my database for test dashboard page load by putting 100 users load .

Do i need create 100 different user or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes, In Jmeter you can create multiple threads to hit your endpoint. You can set up and configure this under thread group menu.[image: Jmeter Thread group configuration]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides:

- [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) - where you can specify your database URL and credentials
- [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler - where you can put your query which create test user

The usernames/passwords can be parameterized using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

More information: [How to Create Test Data in a Database with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter)